# Scraping a page inside a main page?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm doing a web app that searches all the shoe sizes that are in stock for each model of shoe.

So for example, for a website having a list of shoes:

`http://www.soccer.com/shop/footwear/?page=1&pageSize=12&query=*&facet=ads_f40502_ntk_cs%253A%2522Nike%2522`

I'll need to go inside each link to scrape this information.
Is there any way I can effectively do this with Scrapy (or something else)? Or is it impossible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and it is one of `Scrapy`'s core functionalities.

For example, for scraping every shoe on this site what you would do is:

In your spider variables `start_urls = ['http://www.soccer.com/shop/footwear/?page=1&pageSize=12&query=*&facet=ads_f40502_ntk_cs%253A%2522Nike%2522']`

Then on your `parse(self, response)` your code should look like this:

```
for shoe_url in response.xpath(<ENTER_THE_XPATH>).extract()
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(shoe_url), callback=self.parse_shoe)
```

and in the method `parse_shoe` which we registered as callback in the `for` loop, you should extract all the information you need.

Now what happens here, is that the spider starts to crawl the URL in `start_urls` and then for every url that meets the xpath we specified it will parse it using the `parse_shoe` function, where you could simply extract the shoe sizes.

You can follow the "Follow Links" tutorial on scrapy's main site on this [link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.3/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) too - it is very clear.

For completeness I looked for the right xpath for you on that page, it should be `'*//ul[@class="medium-3 columns product-list product-grid"]//a/@href'`

Comment: I see, the whole project depended on whether or not this could be possible. I'm glad it does. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for approving!

Comment: Hey btw I'm seeing that it's apparently illegal to web crawl? Would I be doing something illegal by doing this?

Comment: In every page that prohibits crawling it, it would state so in the `robots.txt` file, you can find it in your case in www.soccer.com/robots.txt

For further explanation look at this link http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Ah ok , thanks. Looks like I'm good with that specific address.